# How to show login view controller if user is not logged in on a particular tab?

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6

I have a tab bar controller application that allows for anonymous access however one tab requires the user to be logged in. I am unsure of how to make it happen. I have a login view controller that has a login/cancel option that I can display modally on view load for the tab bar controller however the user can simply press cancel whereby the login view controller is dismissed. I am unclear on my logic as to how to make it happen. How do I have my application flow properly to where users can browse anonymously however keeping one tab an only logged in option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following would probably work:

`[self.tabBarController.selectedViewController presentModalViewController:loginVC
                                                                animated:NO];`

Without knowing more code structure, I can't be more specific on suggestions. The gist of it is, you need to find a navigation controller or an acceptable view controller hierarchy capable of handling presentModalViewController to present your login view controller.